# Swap file is not created on second partition

Tags: windows, pagefile

Because my system partition is not big enough, I want to use another partition, dedicated, to hold the swap file.

So I set up my system to use 800 MB on the system drive, and at least 10 GB on the other partition :

[image: Screenshot of setup]

However, as you can see, only 800 MB total is allocated. (Of course, I rebooted the whole computer many times).

Why can't I use the Swap partition? (FYI, this is *not* a removable drive).

My system drive (c:) is encrypted using bitlocker. Does it matter?

I'm running Windows 8 enterprise X64 with 16GB of Ram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, BitLocker enables the [PagefileOnOSVolume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929820) key to protect your paging file contents from being stored unprotected on an insecure device.

Comment: Do you mean that I should also bitlock my swap partition?

Comment: If you did that, it would then be safe to disable PagefileOnOSVolume. Alternatively, you could keep the paging file only on your OS volume or decide your not that concerned and just disable PagefileonOSVolume.

Comment: Thanks! I can then fill up again the computer with a lot of VM :)